# Recursively inspecting a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, lambda, expression-trees

Let's say I have this expression:

```
e => e.Name.StartsWith(GetArgument())
```

Where `GetArgument()` is defined as follows:

```
public string GetArgument() { return "Lu"; }
```

I want this expression to be translated to the following string:

```
"begins_with(Name, Lu)"
```

I have developed an expression visitor that visits each sub expression in a recursive manner:

```
public class MyExpressionTranslator : ExpressionVisitor, IExpressionTranslator<string>
{
     // ....

     //Implementing IExpressionTranslator<string>
     public string Translate(Expression expr)
     {
          //Begin visiting the expression and its sub expressions
          base.Visit(expr);

          // I need to return the string here
          return null;
     }

     // Overrides method from base class ExpressionVisitor
     protected override MethodCallExpression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expr)
     {
         //This method is called when a method call sub expression is visited

         //For example, I can check if the method being called is "StartsWith"
         if(expr.Method.Name == "StartsWith")
         {
             // I have no idea what to do here
         }

         //Proceeds to visit this expression's sub expressions
         return base.VisitMethodCall(expr);
     }
}
```

I would use this class as follows:

```
MyExpressionTranslator translator = // new MyExpressionTranslator(...)
Expression<Func<SomeClass, bool>> expr = e => e.Name.StartsWith(GetArgument());
string result = translator.Translate(expr);
// result should be "begins_with(Name, Lu)"
```

---

**Providing my base class has a `virtual` visit method for each expression type** *(be it a constant, an argument, a method call, or any other)*, **how can I build the expected string output?**

Comment: You are providing the expected output for a specific case. What about other cases like a property access for example, or a loop maybe?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Actually, I was planning to extend this specific's case solution to any other use case. The core problem here is that I don't know how to create the string recursively. Once that is solved, I can manage to do everything else.

Comment: hint: use private field StringBuilder.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I know I will have to use it, the problem is I don't know how :(

Comment: inside that if statement `builder.Append($"begins_with{...}")`. now for the `...` part. honestly i dont know but look at properties from inside debuger. they will guide you to the right direction. finally to return the string just do `return builder.ToString();`

Comment: In practice, you can't (and shouldn't).  How are you to know that `GetArgument()` can be safely evaluated?  In that context, you can't, nor can you evaluate it anyway.  That's why we have constants known to the compiler.  You're treating that function as if it was a constant, but you don't know that.  You would have to inline the value ahead of generating the original expression.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Something like the below might work. It won't be easy to fill out the other methods though.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<TestObject, bool>> expr = e => e.FirstName.StartsWith(GetArgument());
        var visitor = new MyExpressionTranslator();
        var translation = visitor.Translate(expr); // = "begins_with(FirstName, Lu)"
    }

    static string GetArgument()
    {
        return "Lu";
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface IExpressionTranslator<T>
{
    T Translate(Expression expr);
}

public class MyExpressionTranslator : ExpressionVisitor, IExpressionTranslator<string>
{
    private StringBuilder _sb = null;
    public string Translate(Expression expr)
    {
        _sb = new StringBuilder();
        base.Visit(expr);

        // I need to return the string here
        return _sb.ToString();
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expr)
    {
        if (expr.Method.Name == "StartsWith")
        {
            var mainArg = expr.Arguments[0];
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(mainArg);
            var arg = lambda.Compile()();

            var member = expr.Object as MemberExpression;
            if (member != null)
            {
                _sb.AppendFormat("begins_with({0}, {1})", member.Member.Name, arg);
            }
            else
            {
                //Don't know what you want here.
                _sb.AppendFormat("begins_with({0}, {1}))", "(obj)", arg);
            }
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(expr);
    }
}
```